# Symbol representation for IC

Tags: schematics

Just as a resistor is denoted by symbol R, an inductor with L, are there any representations for ICs, transistors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical usages for reference designators for active components:

- ‘U’ for ICs (including op-amps. 'OA' isn't standard)
- ‘Q’ for transistors of any kind - BJT's, FETs, thyristors, diacs etc.
- ‘D’ for diodes, including LEDs and Zeners
- 'VR' for a Zener or Breakdown diode (alternate to 'D')

These are OrCAD defaults for example. And here's the designatiors for some other passives:

- ‘T’ for transformer
- ‘Y’ for crystal
- 'S' for switch
- 'K' for relay (not 'RLY' - that's not standard either)
- 'F' for fuse

The complete list is defined in ANSI Y32.2/IEEE Std. 315, sec 22, replaced by ASME Y14.44-2008. These are not a free standards but they can be found easily enough.

More here: https://www.eeweb.com/pcb-reference-designators/

And here: https://www.pcblibraries.com/Forum/common-pcb-reference-designators_topic728.html

Answer (score 3):

The default **reference designators** used on the schematic editor on this site can be seen below. There's an obvious preference for a single letter prefix.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHPFr5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, there's no standard. I tend to use IC for ICs, and TR for transistors, whether BJT or FET. This is the only place I've seen OA used for op-amps. I have seen Q used quite often for transistors, and X and U for ICs. T tends to mean transformer rather than transistor, though with the preponderance of one over the other in circuits, I'm surprised that T isn't seen more often to mean transistor.

Comment: Even I have seen transistors name with Q whereas I haven't come across a representation for an IC. This question was asked to me in an interview and I didn't know the answer. Thought I would share it here so that I could get some answers and share the experience

Comment: It's an ill question. You should ask yourself if you want to work in such a company.